# apache reverse proxy to a mTLs service

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, tls1.2

I'm trying setup an apache virtualhost which proxies requests to a third party service.

When apache makes the request to the third party service it needs to include the certificate details so mTLS connection to third party is successful.

here is my vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ProxyPass "/svc" "https://www.thirdpartymtlssite.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/svc" "https://www.thirdpartymtlssite.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

i have enabled

```
LoadModule proxy_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so,
LoadModule proxy_http_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

I have the certificate and key files which  i can add in the following way

```
SSLCertificateFile "<cert for mTls server>"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "<Key for mTls server>"
```

but im not sure this is correct as that appears to be how you would provide certificate chain if you are running ssl coming into the server.

Is this even possible or should i be looking at another technology to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trust the root CA that signed the first certificate in the certificate chain that the third party site sends to you in the TLS negotiation. This is specified in the SSLProxyCACertificateFile directive, which points to a file containing the root CA cert.

Comment: im familiar with some of the the process i.e.  i create csr, third party signs csr.  But how do i then trust the root CA